# Firebug debugging confusing in JavaScript switch statement

Tags: javascript, firebug, switch-statement

I have the following switch statement in JavaScript :

```
switch(scrollable.direction){
  case "top" :
    break;
  case "left" :
    break;
  case "right" :
    scrollable.select("."+lineCssClass).invoke("setStyle", {float: "right"});
    break;
  case "bottom" :
    alert("Bottom scrolling not implemented yet ! Sorry !");
    return;
}
```

(the "invoke" bit is prototype.js, but it's no relevant to the question anyway)

It is inside a function. I want that if the value is `"bottom"` a message is displayed and the method execution stops.

The problem is that if the value is e.g. `"top"`, the `break` is executed, but the execution jumps to the `return;` statement instead of exiting the switch statement.

I actually solved the problem by adding an additionnal `break;` after the return, which is actually dead code since it can never be executed.

But I would be curious to know why it executed the "return" in the first place ?

**Edit: I am sorry**, the "return" wasn't actually executed. I was stepping through the code using Firebug and it actually stepped on and highlighted the "return" line, but it wasn't executed.

There are other problems in my code that cause it not to work as expected, and I was wrongly blaming this.

Comment: What code comes after the switch in that function? Maybe the problem is there.

Comment: Not reproducable: `(function(){switch(1){case 1:break;return 3}})()`.

Comment: Please provide a more complete example.

Comment: Are you sure you got that behavior? I tried it with jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/AHNh2/) and couldn't reproduce it (change the value in the switch to "top" or "bottom").

Comment: @Pierre Henry: Don't delete this question - since others people might also get confused by Firebug in the same way that you did I would suggest you instead rephrase your question title and post an answer of your own explaining the problem and its solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the edit I made to the question, the problem was actually not that the return; was executed, but that Firebug gave the impression it was when I went step by step through the switch statement.

Alsot, after some more tests, **I can reproduce this weird thing only when I enclose the switch/case statement in a try block.**

As missingno suggested I will leave this question in case other people are confused by this behaviour of Firebug.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My bet is that your `scrollable.direction` is giving you a worng value that is not a real direction.

Add a `default` clause to your switch statement (as you should always do, btw) to check it out

```
switch(scrollable.direction){
  /*...*/
  case "bottom" :
    alert("Bottom scrolling not implemented yet ! Sorry !");
    return;
  default:
    console.log(scrollable.direction, 'is not a direction');
    break;
}
```

Comment: even if it would be a "wrong" direction or value, it would not jump to the 'bottom' label.

Comment: @jAndy: That makes sense, but that seems to be the problem here... it doesn't make sense. I'd point out that OP stated that it jumps to the `return`, not necessarily the `case "bottom":`. I'm guessing @missingno is on the right track.

Comment: @RightSaidFred: I don't get that? It cannot jump to the `return` without jumping to the 'bottom' label before. My guess is, the OP is completely off and confused here. That is guaranteed not whats happening.

Comment: Firebug actually gave the impression that it jumped directly to the "return" without goign through the case:bottom (see edit)! So I was actually off and confused, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Similar sort of issue occurred with me while using Firebug but on the IF statement.

```
if(multiship == true) 
{
// do something
} 
else 
{
// do something
}
```

The debugger showed that the script execution took the if path instead of having multiship variable equal to false.